Setup project to install an Excel Add-In. How to do it?
It's been a long time since I needed to create a setup project.
However, now I need to create a setup project that will install an Excel add-in.
I can check if the Excel is installed by a ‘Registry search’ (by checking the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\InstallRoot\Path registry value) and it works, as shown in the images below.


But, unfortunately, when I try to use the registry property [OFFICE_INSTALL_PATH] as the default location for the [INSTALLDIR] property (as shown below) the installer, when executing, goes haywire.

The installer thinks that the path is in a network location.

As it can be seen I'm using the default Setup project.
Is it possible to do what I want here?

After much tinkering, I went back to the drawing board and ended up using NSIS.
It provides a much better installer solution.
